# react smooth scrollbar from idiotWu does not work?

Tags: reactjs, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to use this scrollbar in my react project:

https://github.com/idiotWu/react-smooth-scrollbar

But when I install the module into my react project and I tried following the instructions, nothing happens.  I still get the regular scrollbar.  I don't get any errors/warnings in the console.

Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "johnproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/Main.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap-modal": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^7.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.8",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {app:'./src/Main.js'},

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].bundle.js',
  path: 'build',
    publicPath: '/smoothscroll/build/'
  },
  plugins: [
    /*
        // This plugin minifies all the Javascript code of the final bundle
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle:   true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
            },
        }),
    */
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name:      'main', // Move dependencies to our main file
            children:  true, // Look for common dependencies in all children,
            minChunks: 2, // How many times a dependency must come up before being extracted
        })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]},
      { test: /\.(jpg|gif|png|eot|woff|svg|ttf)(\?.*)?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
```

Here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Web</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/smoothscroll/node_modules/smooth-scrollbar/dist/smooth-scrollbar.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/smoothscroll/build/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my src/Main.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Scrollbar from 'react-smooth-scrollbar';


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
      <Scrollbar
        speed={100}
        damping={0.1}
        overscrollDamping={0.2}
        thumbMinSize={20}
        renderByPixels={true}
        continuousScrolling={true}>
        <ol>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>add int 100 more rows of these</li>
        </ol>
      </Scrollbar>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

What am I doing wrong?

MORE INSTRUCTIONS
To reproduce my issue, simply create the four files above within a folder called smoothscroll such that the project will be visible at `http://whatever.com/smoothscroll` .  Then run `npm install`.  Then run `webpack`.  Then visit the `http://whatever.com/smoothscroll` to see that the site still uses native scrollbar.

Here's my version of the project:

https://github.com/johnlai2004/react-smooth-scrollbar

Comment: NOTE -- i updated the link to the proper react version of smooth-scrollbar

Comment: Could you create a quick repo with the problem

Comment: Hi Hussein, here it is -- https://github.com/johnlai2004/react-smooth-scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an area scrollable, the container should be smaller than the contents. So the solution is:

```
ol { height: 500px }
```